# How do I compare 2 lists with different set of elements , in an adapter onBind()?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview

I am currently using an adapter  to return the set of items in 2 lists, such that :

```
private List<ListResponse.Repo> mListResponseList;
private List<MyEvents.Event> mMyEventsList;
```

Now, MyListResponse.Repo and MyEvents.Event , get me json objects with complete list of events for the first one (ListResponse.Repo) and some select few events for the second one ( MyEvents.Event)

In my get item count for the adapter I return ListResponse.Repo size as follows:

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mListResponseList != null && mListResponseList.size() > 0 ) {
            return mListResponseList.size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Please note : mListResponseList.size() is list of all events, so it usually returns all the events in the list ( say 6) , and if I were to use mMyEventsList.size ,it is always less than or equal to the list of items in mListResponseList as its practically derived from there (as these are specific events from the main list that i am retrieving in another endpoint).

Now , I have an issue where I am trying to display only the events where the event title in mMyEventsList matches the event title returned from mListResponseList. The only issue is since the size of list returned by all events is larger than the size of the list returned by mMyEventsList, I usually get index out of bounds exception when I try to compare them. I tried using the following code:

```
if (position < mMyEventsList.size()){

if(mMyEventsList.get(position).getEventTitle().equals(repo.getTitle())
     {
                    cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      }
}
```

but it does not return the correct result, displays only one card (instead of 3 or so ,based on the matching titles)

The following hardcoded string works for the given test scenario( where first list has 8 items and second has 4,), but its still hardcoded(if the second list is to return more than 4 ,this wont work), I would like to introduce something dynamic(also by making sure the app doesnt crash if i compare the lists with different sizes with index out of bounds exception) ,for as the list items change, the content will change aswell.

Any idea how to make the following comparison dynamic, so it returns the expected result, where it compares items in list 1 with items in list 2 and  sets the cardview for that particular element as visible if the titles match, otherwise it sets the visibility to gone, if the titles do not match. here's the hardcoded code I am using as of now, just would like to make it more dynamic by introducing some kind of loop which would work for my case(didn't have any luck with it so far ).

```
    public void onBind(int position) {
                super.onBind(position);
 if(mMyEventsList.get(0).getEventTitle().equals(repo.getTitle()) && mMyEventsList.get(0).getIsAttending() ||
                        mMyEventsList.get(1).getEventTitle().equals(repo.getTitle()) && mMyEventsList.get(1).getIsAttending() ||
                        mMyEventsList.get(2).getEventTitle().equals(repo.getTitle()) && mMyEventsList.get(2).getIsAttending() ||
                        mMyEventsList.get(3).getEventTitle().equals(repo.getTitle()) && mMyEventsList.get(3).getIsAttending()){
                    cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

}
```

Thanks in advance!
 (p.s: sorry to make it so long, just wanted to explain what I basically need, which is a dynamic comparison loop, that outputs the result of items with matching titles (even if the lists are of different size based on different number of elements)

Comment: you check if the item in Position 1 in the derived list is exactly the item in Position 1 of your original list, but if your derived list contains items 1,3 and 6 of the original list this would work only for item 1. You Need to check the whole original list for each item in the derived list.

Comment: @DominikWuttke thanks for your response. can you explain your scenario with code. would be easier to understand that way. I just want to make my hardcoded code dynamic but couldnt figure out how to go about it, any ideas?

Comment: As you said, `mMyEventsList` is derived from `mListResponseList` then why are you doing comparison. Just show all the items available in `mMyEventsList`. @AngelaHeely

Comment: @sagarsuri it is derived in parts by list 1, and doesn't really have all the elements I need to display in the cardview. Say list 1 has image and other attributes, while list 2 just has title and another unnecessary attribute, and bother of these are 2 separate endpoints created on server so I cant really change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare item 1 from list 1 with item 1 from list 2. Item 2 with item 2 and so on, if the second list is a Derivate from the first one and it contains for example item 1,4 and 6. Item 1 of list 2 is item 1 of list 1, but item 2 is item 4 and they won't ever match again. You Need to compare each item of list 2 with every item of list 1. For example

```
public void onBind(int position) {
            super.onBind(position);
cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
for (int i = 0;i<mListResponseList;i++){
if (//Item from List 2 at Position 'Position' equals item on Position i of originallist){
cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
break;
}
```

You basically iterate through your whole List 1 and check if any item equals your item in list 2 and if they are equal you set the cardview visible, otherwise it stays Gone as defined onBind.

Modification:

```
cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            for (int i = 0;i<mMyEventsList.size();i++){
                if (mMyEventsList.get(i).getEventTitle().equals(repo.getTitle()) ) {
                    cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: so for this line : "if (//Item from List 2 at Position 'Position' equals item on Position i of originallist){" will it be "mMyEventList.get(i).getTitle().equals(repo.gettitle())"? also, will it compare each and every item in list 1 against each item in list 2, without a crash?

Comment: What is repo.gettitle()? does your responselist not have something like "mMyEventList.get(i).getTitle()". You try to loop through the wrong list in your Code example

Comment: I am assuming by" for (int i = 0;i<mListResponseList;i++){
you meant to compare against mListResponseList.size. The issue is mListResponseList.size could be, say 7, and mMyEventist can have size of 4 , which means if comparison for position = 6 , will lead to an index out of bounds exception, as mMyEventList.get(6). get title does not exist or if you restrict it to a lower number where position < mMyEventlist.size() , it will not even compare the higher position elements in mListResponseList with mMyEventList based on the logic above. which is where I am stuck

Comment: if you compare mMyEventList.get(Position) with every item in the responselist and responselist is 7 items and eventlist 4 items. It will compare item 1 in eventlist with item1 to 7 in responselist, item 2,3 and 4 of the eventlist too. Your eventlist only has 4 items and this function will only be called for These 4 items, that's why you use the Position you get from the onBind.

Comment: I understand what your expected logic was. i made the modification and posted the answer that actually works from your code into your answer. Thanks for helping out, it actually helped steer in the right direction. +25 for you

Comment: any idea about this one ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req

Answer (score 0):

code ArrayList results = new ArrayList<>(); // Loop arrayList2 items for (Person person2 : arrayList2) { // Loop arrayList1 items boolean found = false; for (Person person1 : arrayList1) { if (person2.id == person1.id) { found = true; } } if (!found) { results.add(person2.id); } }

Comment: can you explain with respect to my code. if there is a straight forward way of doing this, seems like the above approach maybe unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

@Angela Heely You should just update your adapted with the new list

Comment: the second list has just the title and another attribute, i want to display the  items in the first list (which has title and image and other items i need) only if the title in second and first list match. how do i go about that?

Comment: Try to compare the two lists and generate a filtered list that you can update your adapter with.

Comment: code ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

// Loop arrayList2 items
for (Person person2 : arrayList2) {
    // Loop arrayList1 items
    boolean found = false;
    for (Person person1 : arrayList1) {
        if (person2.id == person1.id) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        results.add(person2.id);
    }
}

Comment: This should be added as a comment. Not as an answer.